# Poisson Summation Formula with vector functions

Tags: poisson-summation-formula

I want to derive the form of the Poisson Summation Formula as in Equation (6) of this [this paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271560/1-s2.0-S0550321305X17060/1-s2.0-S0550321305007133/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEJD%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIA6%2Bs4AmuMNXniHOvUxKcva4smoRpFLIUtBrl44pCXUCAiEA3PrhUD8T5cz6g%2FGalWQaY65ZRylH0fY%2FQZxUopNB1YEqswUISBAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDE9jRRhl4CwZO1MxLCqQBccuTk6u1y49NV9N4KVQKMy5bWjtcPYwYZntJDsYed7CxbkWpAq0URzla1GMBz25nDGU6BBactAjAE1ZMDY45DHVBYaVjl9T7P6AwEQpzBrXlsqmM2iD2wqewVwdqdhI22CwfUZ24%2F7NeY%2BdQL25gRDvDi%2FksD21DW69%2B70pNTxETfBIcDaQALODXuf4q2SpxpB5ykNnWcyBuwuxVVGuqx0zaigvQAnJW6U225QtfU%2BQ3whpLHu1fjYZL9Qr7bcNhRigUxI4AbuULkQZ2p3lEQ6HWmDDOVOiMxZKvqQ05RBtBZrEoJLoppg0wm%2B0H91wPzLvLzPN7jR%2BklSNtW5S7qYgFjLLvzrKH6SdAncz%2BL%2F66mTGab2nbUkgx4ZVXNEaaTSQn2NFhyWMlbQOEWDJoPyiSmsiT1xm6GkDjyqf8R%2FAfkjDFzbtaAm0j7FmNR5RwtNdy%2FNUSEdlJ9Tbiu1pS87nA176aTSSC%2FJCGeRN2U1B%2FBmuzT%2BRKViT9JVGmWMRCgKfYs9jcN5kXvwfkpE6P76ltv1bNxWUYd00%2FXuK9m4r7W3mFiqpWPFrNqCWapnUXQf6jRp8Wg0MqYsiYSFQHg1I%2B9mRMTJwcVj%2B%2Be7jcXwxALEq997fDlxCF%2BHmrbw4Fhj0joD0vS6bUi7MF1IbqAyffYvgFdwjS1iNGU71LY23JsTpyZ9FxPMjQ3B1O0ECKYuVWKWLUWIF94V%2BUIQ72xo6E8olFF996n%2FqG%2FjJipCgWaKn5jdVcAeD%2FtOX0baIQJw2LgDqY%2F70ynb94kzgVQ36lqn0TiYma8sbR6Me1L14fW8ZsntLpebqmw%2Bv%2BBTX6rX9LfW%2BCEjHnqlillsvsn0zKPC%2FA6%2BVJvYuj6fQNiVaMKKJuq0GOrEBouvImnSvfw4KymzlhOWH8DfHv76SkYCR2aZhAZMHXZTq2d8V9xJxeAaNN6ky%2B2EFCz2zFAibcBzZZQ4x90KvYNMW8mVB6GxvywlrI2krXXrSaEbqOola343qnMZ1RjJuFlykISy4DTGFCM9Qo2IzJ4GN%2FcJnqW8WIpJK8P%2FbuVphNJSPF%2FJHlNq%2FH7ims3qa%2F1l3mkfnfEoUN9moSYiFwO3E1RlM5Uic5YQlP2%2F6AkFk&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20240122T151725Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY4WSBEIU3%2F20240122%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=51daf546262ac0c0aad92d41070ec2e045aacbea46b49e3bdfddb1d750c4bd78&hash=322695421d3118536fd6682db0f64daa14eb367534d684ac2a668964be70649a&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0550321305007133&tid=spdf-6b49317f-98c2-474c-b027-971ec3de98b2&sid=cda27f0733458040285b9b827c7916021cf8gxrqa&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=0f155b5b5a5703525d5304&rr=8498c383cb8e680c&cc=us)

which is
$$ \frac{1}{L^3} \sum_{\vec{k}} g(\vec{k}) = \int \frac{d^3 k}{(2\pi)^3} g(\vec{k}) + \sum_{\vec{l} \neq \vec{0} } \int \frac{d^3 k}{(2\pi)^3} e^{iL \vec{l} \cdot \vec{k}} g(\vec{k}) $$

where the summation on the left side is over all integer values of $\vec{n} = (n_1, n_2, n_3)$ and $\vec{k} = \frac{2\pi}{L} \vec{n}$ while that on the right is over integral values of $\vec{l} = (l_1, l_2, l_3)$ excluding $\vec{l} = (0,0,0)$

For context, the paper uses this formula to relate discrete sums over momenta of particles and integrals over a continuous spectrum in infinite volume.

I'm honestly a bit lost, and would appreciate a full derivation, but any hints on how this can be obtained would be greatly appreciated!